# Share a private git repository on GitHub with a specific user as read-only

Tags: git, github, readonly

I'm finally trying to learn how to git, so I'm writing a rather extensive thesis with version control on GitHub. I have a *free* GitHub pro account, thanks to my University, so I can add private repositories.

I need to add my supervisor, so he has access to the documents, but I want his his GitHub account to have read-only rights.

How do I allow read-only access to a private repository on GitHub with a specific user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering that a [collaborator on a simple GitHub repo has push access](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository/), you have a few options:

- [transferring your repo to an organization](https://help.github.com/articles/transferring-a-repository/) (that you have created): you can then restrict push: Then you can [add an external collaborator](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-outside-collaborators-to-repositories-in-your-organization/) with only read access:
  [image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/repository/org-repo-collaborators-choose-permissions.png]
  <sup>(the image shows wirte access, but the point is: you can select "Read")</sup>
- or you can protect and [restrict write access to branch](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-protected-branches/) (but you need to do that for *all* branches)

Comment: If I understand this correctly, I'd have to pay to get a git organisation, which  is not something I'd like to do.
I'll most likely have only the master or at most a second branch, so that would not be that much of a problem. But this only protects it from force pushes and deletes, right?

Comment: @boolean.is.null yes, protection against push and delete indeed.