# How to grant access to download or clone a PRIVATE repository to users?

Tags: github

I have a private repository in Github. I want to share my code with multiple learners in my class. Basically, I am okay if they clone my code or download it. But I don't want them to change anything in my code.

Is there any way by which they can clone my code and create a pull request?

1. I don't want to give them access to merge the code in my branches (master and develop)
2. They may create a pull request but they should not be able to merge that pull request to master or develop.

Comment: Sounds like you just want to make your branch protected? https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-protected-branches

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share a private git repository on GitHub with a specific user as read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361422/share-a-private-git-repository-on-github-with-a-specific-user-as-read-only)